# which backend stack for development e-commerce mobile app?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, flutter, mobile, backend

I am learning flutter is really a good technology to build mobile apps ,my project is an e-commerce app,but I am confused about which route I will take for back-end.  I read about Firebase and how its good but I read also its limited by 200 users concurrently on a real-time database so it will not be a good option so the research led me to express.js"Node.js" + SQL or MongoDB \ Laravel + SQL, get in mind that I have a good experience with men stack (Express with MongoDB) but I hear that MongoDB is too expensive to be host also I need to know if MongoDB can be a great deal in a free cluster or not with my e-commerce app .

Answer (score 0):

If you have good experience in **Express**  you probably go with it. And if you are not ok with MongoDb, Specially a paid version, then you definitely go with **SQL**. But it will be a bit complex than MongoDB and take extra time for you to manually control your CRM database for E-commerce Application.

On the other hand  MySQL has no limit on the number of databases. The underlying file system may have a limit on the number of directories.

MySQL has no limit on the number of tables. The underlying file system may have a limit on the number of files that represent tables. Individual storage engines may impose engine-specific constraints. InnoDB permits up to 4 billion tables. This will give **SQL** a plus point at this stage.

But **laravel** is also a good technology I am not so familiar with it. so I cant suggest it.